# Accessing yelp API points in Python

Tags: python, api, yelp

I have a yelp response as linked [here](http://pastebin.com/d9Lz4sKR). I am trying to print out just a list of the names returned. I have tried the following:

```
print response['name']
print response[0]
print response[0]['name']
```

And all seem to give error. How do I access a list of just place names? Or just one place name?

Comment: What error did you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for b in response['businesses']:
    print b.get('name', 'missing')
```